# How can I set up a local MTA on NixOS?

Tags: perl, nixos, mail-transport-agent, ssmtp

`caff` from [`nixpkgs.pgp-tools`](https://nixos.org/nixos/packages.html#signing-party) seems to require a local MTA to send keys with UIDs signed to the corresponding email addresses. (It uses perl's `Mail::Mailer` for that.)

**How can I set up a local MTA on my Laptop running NixOS?** Can and should I use the [`networking.defaultMailServer.*`](https://nixos.org/nixos/options.html#networking.defaultmailserver.) options, which seem to configure sSMTP?

As I use my Laptop as a personal computer, I'm not looking for how to set up a full-blown email server (with multiple accounts/users, mailboxes, etc.). However, to be usefull for `caff`, mails should obviously be sent out (using the same remote SMTP server as my MUA uses), not just delivered to a local directory or something.

Answer (score 0):

Either use the module for ssmtp to setup a daemon-less mta (requires your mua to support the sendmail) and nullmailer that also listens on local port 25.

Comment: I don't think my MUA (Mozilla Thunderbird) should actually come into play, should it? I just want to use the same "settings" (remote mailserver and mail account) as my MUA, but am fine with re-configuring those settings for the MTA separately. (I don't expect any MTA to be able to read my Thunderbird settings.) Or am I mixing things up here?

Comment: Also, can you go into more detail on how the suggested setup(s?) would be done? (E.g. what to put into `/etc/nixos/configuration.nix`)

Answer (score 0):

While it doesn't integrate with NixOS config <s>nicely</s> at all, you can install `msmtp` in your user or system profile and configure it via `~/.msmtprc` as you would on a traditional Linux distribution.